# overloading << operator with template to change output

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've got a class called number and I'm needing help with operator overloading.

```
template<class T>
class Number{
public:
    Number(T _numerator,T _denominator){
        numerator = _numerator;
        denominator = _denominator;
    }
    ~Number(){
        ;
    }
    T GetData(){
        return numerator/denominator;
    }
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Number c)     //output
    {
        out << c.numerator/c.denominator;
        return out;
    }
    void SetData(T _numerator,T _denominator){
        numerator = _numerator;
        denominator = _denominator;
    }

private:
    T numerator;
    T denominator;
};
```

that's what I have that works but I would like another operator overloaded like:

```
template<class X>
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Number c)     //output
{
    out << (X)c.numerator/(X)c.denominator;
    return out;
}
```

that way I can call cout like this(I know I could just change Number's template to a double but that's not what I want):

```
Number<int> t(10,23);
std::cout << t<double> << "\n";
```

however that doesn't compile.
so is there anyway to use templates like that? or an alternate solution other than just creating a normal function?

Comment: in general you should use C++ cast operators instead of C style cast operator `()`. ie `static_cast`.

Comment: I just did a quick google search, and I think your right. Is there any advantage of a c-style cast?

Comment: Yes, I still happen to use C-style cast sometimes when I am lazy. But I don't think lazyness is good. C++ cast operators are much safer. static_cast above all.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're thinking too complicated about it and the way you want to use it, won't work.

When you need it to be Double, make it double, so therefore I added here the new member as()

```
template<class T>
class Number{
public:
    Number(T _numerator,T _denominator){
        numerator = _numerator;
        denominator = _denominator;
    }
    ~Number(){
        ;
    }
    T GetData(){
        return numerator/denominator;
    }
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Number c)     //output
    {
        out << c.numerator/c.denominator;
        return out;
    }
    void SetData(T _numerator,T _denominator){
        numerator = _numerator;
        denominator = _denominator;
    }

    template<typename U>
    Number<U> as(){
        return Number<U>(U(numerator), U(denominator));
    }

private:
    T numerator;
    T denominator;
};


Number<int> t(10,23);
std::cout << t.as<double>() << "\n";
```

Comment: thank you very much. I'd rather there be a way I could use my method, but it doesn't look like that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can get close to what you're looking for any number of ways. The *exact* syntax you want is impossible unfortunately , as the type you desire must be pinned through *something* (be it a function, a constructed object, whatever).

Vinzenz has shown you how to you can pin it through a member function. This is how you can pin it through an alternate constructor.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Number
{
    // allow friending alternate types
    template<typename> friend class Number;

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Number c)     //output
    {
        out << c.GetData();
        return out;
    }

public:
    Number(T _numerator = 0, T _denominator = 1)
        : numerator(_numerator)
        , denominator(_denominator)
    {
    }

    // constructor for alt-type conversion
    template<typename X>
    Number(const Number<X>& obj)
        : numerator(static_cast<T>(obj.numerator))
        , denominator(static_cast<T>(obj.denominator))
    {
    }

    // getter should be const
    T GetData() const
    {
        return numerator/denominator;
    }

    void SetData(T _numerator,T _denominator)
    {
        numerator = _numerator;
        denominator = _denominator;
    }

private:
    T numerator;
    T denominator;
};

int main()
{
    Number<int> num(10,5);      // regular construction
    Number<float> flt = num;    // alternate type construction

    // operator tests
    std::cout << num << '\n';
    std::cout << flt << '\n';
    std::cout << Number<double>(num) << std::endl; // temp construction

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
2
2
2
```

Best of luck.